# Launch image displaying after deleteing

Tags: iphone, xcode

I deleted launch image from launch image option.Still i am getting launch image?I do not know where it is from loading?

Comment: what is the name of ur image ? if its default.png change the name

Comment: Also, you could try to make a clean in xCode.

Comment: i deleted it.still loading from somewhere else.

Comment: Delete your app from Simulator/device. Do Project->Clean. Re-build and install app again

Comment: if u run ur app in device, this issue will not occur now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the name of your image as would be defaultly saved as Default.png, As xcode changes the name of the image itself whether you add the name of the image yourself or not.

And as The Dude suggested clean your code and reset your simulator if you are working on it and build your project again , then run and see.